# How to do, to don´t get blocked my app - Android

Tags: android, screen, block

Ok, first, sorry for my english.
Second, i searched in Google and StackOverFlow and i didn´t find anything.

My question is:
How to do, to don´t get blocked my app, like when you are in your app for example, and you aren´t touching it for 30 seconds (i think) the phone will put a black screen and will get blocked.

How to make this don´t happen?
Thanks for the answer :)
PD: I am newbie D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about controlling the screen so the display timeout doesn't cause the screen to turn off then you can have a look at the `WindowManager`. You can set different `flags` so control how the window is treated. Make sure to pay special attention to the description of the flags you want to use and API levels. To keep the screen on, for instance, you could do something like

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

[WindowManager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)

[WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

If this is not what you are talking about then please do your best to explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Yes, exactly this, thanks!
Sorry, maybe if i type that its for a flashlight you could understand me better.
I can´t vote up your answer because i have no points D:

Comment: LOL, I thought i could elect all XD

Comment: Nope, sorry, just one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks!  I can´t vote up your answer because i have no points D: